# How to define inner field in sencha-touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

```
items: [
         {
          xtype: 'textareafield',
           label: 'references',
           items: [{
                    xtype:'textareafield',
                      }
                 ]
                   }]
```

I want to create a textarea field inside a textarea, but it's displaying only one textareafield and not showing inner textareafield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items` config does not work here as it's not available to `Ext.field`, try `component` config instead, something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    component: {
      xtype: 'container', 
      layout: 'vbox', 
      items: [
      {
        xtype: 'textareainput', 
        flex: 3,
      }, 
      {
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        flex: 1, 
      }
      ]},
},
```

P/S: Behine the scene, Sencha Touch 2 sets `component` config to `{xtype: "textareainput"}` by default, so with this method, you can insert whatever you want, such as buttons, and so on.

Comment: now i want to add border in inner field how's it's possible??

Comment: it's just only the matter of CSS customization